IF Statement Not Returning Updated Measure from other table after filter/slice
I want to create a single field in my dataset to filter on.
This will update to reflect a filter onn another table.
In the other table I have created values that reflect the level of geographic aggregation I want to report for from my main data table (e.g. national, regional, sub_region_1 etc).
I am doing this in order to create a single field to filter on in my main data table. This will allow me to dynamically aggregate a large dataset to these different geographic levels based on the filter.
I have tried reflecting the outcome of the filter in a Measure in order to reference this in an if statement in a field in my main data table
The Measure reflects the filtered geo level as a value but the IF statement for the new field will not update based on the outcome of the filter.
I have one table which I have called Level_Table and this contains a field "geo_level" with entries "National", "Regional", "sub-regional", "service" etc. This is the field in the page filter/slicer.
I have created a Measure in this table called "Level_Measure" and this is simply Level_Measure = MIN('Level_Table'[geo]) in order to return a single text value of the filtered geo level for use in formulas in other tables.
When I filter/slice the geo field (single selection only) then the measure appears to update with the value selected. I am hoping to refence this in an if statement in another table.
Into my _data table I have created a field called "Location". This dataset has the regional sub levels in as fields.
I have attempted for this field Location = IF('Level_Table'[Level_Measure] = "National","National","FAIL")
(As a test). I was expecting this to return "National" as the measure was showing "National".
It seems that the if statement is not capable of reaching the updated state after the measure has been filtered.
I initially tried to just reference MIN('Level_Table'[geo]) in the if statement which led me to attempting the measure. This worked so far as it recognised the pre-filtered state and just returned the first alphabetical from Level_Table.
The reason I want this in a field in my main data table is so that I can have one graph and depending on the level I have selected then the other geographical levels will for into the Location field which will be my x axis - this will remove the need for multiple graphs based on the other fields.
I think this is a good way of doing this without needing to create aggregations for these levels in the dataset but I can't quite figure out how to get Power BI to be reactive enough.
It'd be great if there was a IF(REFRESH('Level_Table'[Level_Measure]) = "National","National","FAIL") ability or something along those lines but I know that's fantasy. I have tried using FILTER(), SELECTEDVALUE() among others.
I'd be grateful for any advice either getting the if statement to update post-slice or an alternative
This should help explain what I'm trying to do. Next step is how to do IFS()!
enter image description here

Solved it - you create a parameter from the geographic area level fields and use that for the axis then create a slicer from the parameter. I also added a dummy field called national = "National" for a global top level.
code
Location_Parameter = {
("National", NAMEOF('_data'[national]), 0),
("Regional", NAMEOF('_data'[region]), 1),
("Sub-Regional", NAMEOF('_data'[sub_region]), 2),
("Service", NAMEOF('_data'[service_name]), 3)
}
code
